# Is this possible in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

[image]

I am wondering if it is possible to quickly create something like this in Tikz. In particular, I am concerned with making the zig-zag line, which has these properties:

- Each star is on a clearly identifiable horizontal "level"
- Each star is exactly *between* two of the characters (alphas and betas) along the top

Having the zig-zag line line up with the tree on the right would be a plus too!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is for You "quickly create"?

Comment: What do you have so far? If the zig-zag line is the problem, how are you creating the rest of the graphic?

Comment: It might be easier to move the alphas and betas around to match the stars.

Comment: @cfr I was thinking of using absolute positioning, but wanted to know if there was an easier way. I guess one different way to think of it is that there is a grid (similar to the "array" environment in LaTeX) on which the stars sit.

Comment: @OSjerick I guess "quickly" was not the right word, sorry! I am looking for a natural way to make a zig-zag line with the above properties. Please see my above comment for my other thoughts.

Comment: @blf: What is your picture explaining? Or what do you try to express?

Answer (score 12):

There are two problems in this drawing. First the zig-zag line, second the top formula which has special alignment requirements.

The following code suggests solutions for these problems. There is a short explanation:

1. First, each position for each asterisk is defined as a named coordinate, with names `n0`, `n1`, `n2`, and so on, but nothing is drawn yet. These names are useful to later annotate the figure or to add more auxiliar lines. Their positions are specified by a string of `1` and `-1`, which refers to the vertical position relative to the previous one.
2. The zig-zag line is drawn across the sequence `(n0)--(n1)--(n2)--` etc
3. Some auxiliar horizontal lines are drawn between some pairs of `n\i`/`n\j`.
4. Stars. For each `\i` in 0..19 a star is drawn at `(n\i)`.
5. Finally, and here is where syntax gets ugly, the formula is drawn at top. To draw the formula I split it in "fragments" so that each fragment is drawn at coordinates which are multiple of 0.5.

   For example, the first fragment is `\beta`, and this is drawn at x=0.5, which is the middle point between `n0` and `n1`. The second fragment is the left bracket (`\bigg[`) which is drawn at x=1, which is at the vertical of `n1`. The third fragment is `a`, drawn at x=1.5, which is at the middle of `n1` and `n2`, and so on.

   Those fragments are specified manually, separated by commas.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
    star/.style = {
        fill=white, circle, 
        inner sep=0pt,
    }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=6mm, y=6mm]

    % 1. define n0, n1, n2,  ... n19
    \coordinate (n0) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (prev) at (n0);
    \foreach [count=\i] \d in {1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1} {
        \coordinate (n\i) at ($(prev)+(1,\d)$);
        \coordinate (prev) at (n\i);
    };

   % 2. Draw zig-zag
   \draw[thick] (n0) \foreach \n in {1,...,19} { -- (n\n) } ;

   % 3. Draw some horizontal lines
   \foreach \a/\b in {2/18,3/15,6/14,7/9,11/13} {
     \draw[thin, gray, dashed] (n\a) -- (n\b);
   };

   % 4. Draw stars
   \foreach \n in {0,...,19} {
       \node[star] at (n\n) {$\star$};
   };

   % 5. Draw formula 
   \def\L{(}  % Parenthesis cannot be used as part of \foreach
   \def\R{)}  % so I had to define here a macro for them
   \foreach [count=\i] \txt in {\beta,\bigg[,
      a,\Big(,a,\L,a,,\beta,\R\big(,
      a,\L,a,,a,,\beta,,\beta,\R\L,
      a,,a,,\beta,,\beta,\R,\beta,\big),
      \beta,\Big)\L,a,,\beta,\R,\beta,\bigg]
   } {
      \node at (0.5*\i,2) {$\txt$};
   };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image: Result]

Comment: I never knew that Tikz had foreach loops! The flexibility there is amazing. Thanks for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 5):

You need to know at least the zig-zag's peaks coordinates.

Because the angles of zig-zag lines and level separation are the same, a simple way to draw the zig-zag with stars is by using decorations.

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes,shapes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1.25cm]
        \draw[thick,postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=star,shape size=2mm,%
        shape sep={1.6cm, between center}},fill=black, shape border rotate=20}]% 
        (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (4,-2) -- (5,-1) -- (8,-4) -- (10,-2) -- (12,-4) -- (16,0) -- (17,-1) -- (19.05,1.05);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Result

[image]

Note that the stars are trying to follow the slope of the line, hence they rotate. I do not know how do not rotate the stars (do not know if you can do that), perhaps using another shape it can be more useful.

I think that a manually drawing is not difficult or annoying. ;)

## Update

Just for general knowledge! :)

I did not know that prevent the slope rotation of the stars it's easy, also improve the star shape, with `shape sloped=false` and setting `star point height`.

```
\draw[thick,postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=star,shape size=2mm,%
shape sep={1.6cm, between center},shape sloped=false},fill=black,star point height=30mm}]%
(0,0) -- (1,1) -- (4,-2) -- (5,-1) -- (8,-4) -- (10,-2) -- (12,-4) -- (16,0) -- (17,-1) -- (19.05,1.05);
```

[image]

Comment: @blf You're Welcome! I wish grant a more useful solution, but I thought this was a simple way (for "quickly create"). :)