# Change dot shape for edge in tikz?

Tags: tikz-styles

I would like to draw an edge between two nodes in tikz, but this edge should be both "dotted" and the dots must be a distinct shape (not dots or dashes). Currently, I am aiming at getting the shape of dots to be a start (*). However, a nice solution would be one that is generic enough that I can define any reasonable shape (say, a triangle, star, hexagon) and get the edge in dotted style.

EDIT: thanks for the comments, I managed to get some stuff working. However, I am still having a bit of issues. Now I have the MWE below:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,=>stealth'] 
        \node[draw,circle,fill=black] (a) at (0,-0.5) {};
        \node[draw,circle,fill=black] (b) at (3.5,-3) {};
        \path[very thick]
            (a) edge[decorate,decoration={crosses, shape evenly spread=6, shape size={.15cm}}] node {} (b)
        ;

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the `shape evenly spread` or `shape sep` options do not seem to work for me.

Does anyone else have the same problem? It doesn't matter how much I change the parameters for either one of them, the figure it generates is always the same.

Comment: See https://tikz.dev/tikz-decorations, there are some "dotted style" examples there with triangles and crosses.

Comment: Or on the site here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150467/is-this-possible-in-tikz/150490 for example, which you could adapt to show only the stars and not the line. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76551/.

Comment: Thanks @Marijn. Your comment helped a lot, but now I am stuck at another point. Do you know what I can do, or if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shape evenly spread` and `shape sep` are not valid options for the `crosses` decoration. But you can use `segment length` to change the distance between the (centers of the) crosses.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[very thick] (0,-.5) edge[decorate, decoration={crosses, segment length=7mm, shape size=.15cm}] node {} (3.5,-3);
        \path[very thick, red] (1,-.5) edge[decorate, decoration={crosses, segment length=5mm, shape size=.15cm}] node {} (4.5,-3);
        \path[very thick, blue] (2,-.5) edge[decorate, decoration={crosses, segment length=2mm, shape size=.15cm}] node {} (5.5,-3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that you can define your own style to make the code a bit simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}

\tikzset{mycrosses/.style={very thick, decorate, decoration={crosses, segment length=#1, shape size=.15cm}},
    mycrosses/.default={7mm}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[mycrosses] (0,-.5) -- (3.5,-3);
        \draw[mycrosses=5mm, red] (1,-.5) -- (4.5,-3);
        \draw[mycrosses=2mm, blue] (2,-.5) -- (5.5,-3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, right! Somehow I was thinking that they applied to crosses as well. My mistake. Thanks, I managed to make it work now!